# How to deal with global variables when calling fortran code in python (e.g. with f2py)?

Tags: python, global-variables, fortran, f2py

I want to run some fortran codes with python and am using **f2py -c -m** for it. However, it seems that only the **FUNCTIONs** are packed into the **.so** file, but not the **PROGRAM**. How can I deal with global variables then? For example, a variable **c** is put in a module

```
MODULE nfw
  double precision :: c
END MODULE nfw
```

,is modified in the PROGRAM, and is used by a FUNCTION in the same file implicitly

```
PROGRAM Compute_Profile
  USE nfw
  c = 5.0
END PROGRAM Compute_Profile

DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION y(x)
  USE nfw
  double precision :: x
  y = c * x
  return
END FUNCTION y
```

How can I call let the function **y(x)** know about the value of **c** in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under your f2py module should be another module, the Fortran one named nfw. It should be there.

```
$ f2py -c -m mod nfw.f90

$ python
import mod
mod.nfw.c

array(0.0)
```

Make sure you compile the source file with the module with f2py.

Comment: It works, thanks! I have packed both files into the library `$ f2py -c -m mod Compute_Profile.f90 nfw.f90`, now I see that I can let mod.y know the value of __c__ by assigning `mod.nfw.c = 2.0` :-)